# Integral with complex perimeter – convergence.

Tags: convergence-divergence, integral-inequality

I've been thinking about this integral for a while.

$$\int_0^{\infty} \left| x^{-2s} \right| \text{d}x$$

for any **complex** $s$ and $x \in (0;\infty)$.

Intuition 'tells' me, this shouldn't converge, but I cannot find any way to prove it – any inequality or hint will be helpful :-)

Comment: I get it’s “obv.” as you put it, but it took me a second there. The $dx$ is kinda mandatory when you write your integrals.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor I added $dx$ term. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $s=a+ib$ so
$$x^{-2s}=x^{-2a}x^{-2ib}$$
Writing $x^{-2ib}$ as 
$$x^{-2ib}=e^{-2ib\log x}$$
So,
$$ |x^{-2s}|=|x^{-2a}e^{-2ib\log x}|=|x^{-2a}||e^{-2ib\log x}|$$
The first factor is a positive real number and the second one is a complex number with modulus equal to 1,so
$$|x^{-2s}|=|x^{-2a}|=x^{-2a}$$
Now you can see that for any value of $a\in R$ the integral diverges. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Since the integrand is absolute value, the imaginary part of $s$ can be ignored.  Assume $s$ is real, then for $s\le 0$ the integral obviously diverges at the upper limit.  For positive $s$  there are two cases to consider.  For $2s\le 1$, the integral diverges at the upper limit.  For $2s\ge 1$, the integral diverges at the lower limit.  Conclusion: the integral is divergent for all values of $s$.